# How can I fllter Amazon SNS messages to match certain S3 Object keys, tags, or metadata on S3 Objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have a S3 bucket which fires events off to a SNS on PUT events. I have several lambda functions subscribing to the SNS, so when a PUT event occurs on S3 all of the lambda functions fire.

The issue is that I only need to process some of the files which are PUT on S3. I currently have filtering logic but it exists in the lambda function. So while I don't process those files(I return early), it still fires the lambda function. It's starting to cost a lot of $$ because I'm invoking the function much more than necessary.

How can I filter which events make it to the Lambda functions? I would like to filter the S3 Objects one of 3 ways:

1) By a partial string match in the Object key. (Prefix and Suffix matching in S3 does not help me...the partial string is in the middle of the object key.)

2) By a tag I apply to certain objects on upload.

3) By metafield I could apply to an objects on upload.

Are any of these strategies possible? I cannot find any documentation that suggests so. If not, how can I achieve the filtering?